Ctrl+Click in vscode (windows wsl), on linux full file paths is opening the wrong path
In the VSCode terminal, if the url file:///home/justin/file.txt is printed, for example, then when I Ctrl+Click the url it will open the open file prompt with the path home/example/file.txt, instead of the expected /home/example/file.txt.
echo "hi" > /home/$(whoami)/test.txt
echo "file:///home/$(whoami)/test.txt"

Then Ctrl+Click the resulting link...

Is this a bug or is there some kind of a misconfigured setting? How can I get it to parse the protocol as file:// not file:///?

weird... https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168634. not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but this might be a bug then? if you raise a new issue ticket, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Here is the new issue link https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211307

It was a bug (Terminal Links Broken #207239 and file protocol links for full paths does not work on integrated terminal with WSL #211307), and it seems to have gotten fixed in 1.89.0.
